# wpf Busy Indicator is not showing up when followed by Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke code

Tags: wpf, dispatcher, busyindicator

I am using wpf busy indicator and setting its `Isbusy` property from viewModel. Aftersetting `Isbusy` property  I want to filter my `ICollectionview` and push it on UI. This `Filter` operation I have put in

```
IsBusy = true;
await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
    new System.Action(() =>
    {
      this.MyCollectionView.Filter = item =>
      {
        Iitem IdName = item as Iitem;
        return Regex.IsMatch(IdName.Name, SearchText, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
      };
    }));
```

Workaround: If I put `Task.Delay(200).Wait();` after setting `IsBusy`, busy indicator will be displayed for some cases.

Comment: What does this **<br>** indicate in WPF?

Answer (score 0):

`Filter` always runs on the UI thread, keeping it too busy to actually update the UI to reflect the `IsBusy` state.

In most cases, `Filter` functions should run fast enough that they don't need any special handling. However, if you're sure that you need to run a time-consuming filter, then the best way to do it is to split into two *different* collections: `MyCollection` and `MyFilteredCollection`. Then, any time `MyCollection` (or the filter) changes, do something like this:

```
IsBusy = true;
var items = MyCollection.ToList();
var filter = SearchText;
MyFilteredCollection = await Task.Run(() =>
    items.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.Name, filter, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)));
IsBusy = false;
```

(this assumes that `IsBusy` will prevent `MyCollection` and `SearchText` from changing).